# Reading .grd file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, gis, raster

Some files in `ESRI grid format`(suffixed in **.grd**) is a geospatial dataset with left low X corner, left low Y corner and value.

The file look like this(using vim to read it):

```
   1 ncols 2880
   2 nrows 1440
   3 xllcorner -180.0
   4 yllcorner  -90.0
   5 cellsize 0.125
   6 nodata_value -999
   7 version 2.0

   8  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
```

For now, I manipulate these files with a manual pre-process approach.

1. Delete the first 7 rows
2. Save the .grd files into `.txt`file.
3. Read the `.txt`file using numpy into a numpy array representing the spatial attribute
4. Combined with the first 7 rows, generate the Lon and Lat array corresponding to the attribute array(For my cas (1440 x 2880))

Now, I want to realize reading the file directly:

- Value   -> Begin from the 8th line
- Longitude -> generater by ncols, cellsize & xllcorner
- Longitude -> generater by nrows, cellsize & yllcorner

#### My attempt

```
 ## Read the first seven lines using LineCache
 ncols = linecache.getline("grd file", 1)
 ......
 ## Read the array using np.loadtxt()
 myArray  = np.loadtxt("grd file", skiprows=7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function for it. Here's a sample (assuming that your line numbers are from vim, not actually present in the file):

```
import numpy as np

def read_grd(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        ncols = int(infile.readline().split()[1])
        nrows = int(infile.readline().split()[1])
        xllcorner = float(infile.readline().split()[1])
        yllcorner = float(infile.readline().split()[1])
        cellsize = float(infile.readline().split()[1])
        nodata_value = int(infile.readline().split()[1])
        version = float(infile.readline().split()[1])
    longitude = xllcorner + cellsize * np.arange(ncols)
    latitude = xllcorner + cellsize * np.arange(nrows)
    value = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=7)

    return longitude, latitude, value
```

Comment: Very nice code. There is one typo: `latitude = xllcorner...` should be `latitude = yllcorner`.